# How can give varying number of inputs to a neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, feature-extraction

I am new to Machine Learning, and looking for a solution to my problem.

I have to recognize characters in Telugu. For which I have been given a dataset with series of (X, Y) coordinates which when plotted obtains a graph which forms the character.

For each character, the seperate file is provided which contain (X, Y) coordinates which form that character when plotted. The number of points (ie: (x,y)) varies from character to character.

I am asked by my supervisor to give X and Y coordinates as features to the neural net. How can I do that? as the number of neurons required for `character-1` and `character-2` vary.
I am not supposed to use CNN but should do as he said.(He's quite rigid)

example:

points `[x,y]`

character-1 `[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]`

character-2 `[2,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,14],[10,16]`

Comment: What about feeding a matrix which has value of 1 on given location and 0 otherwise? For 1st character, `X[1, 2], X[1, 3]` and `X[1, 5]` are 1, all other entries are 0.

Comment: Can you check it now? Please.

Comment: I am supposed to give all x values as input. One x value as an input to one neuron. In the same way y values. The issues is that the number of x values vary from one character to another. How can i dealt with it?

Comment: What you are saying is plotting a graph. Which is same as making an image I was asked not to do so.